# Camera.open() hangs on LG device

Tags: android, android-camera

I wrote a piece of code which records video from camera. Nothing unusual. It works perfectly on several HTC and Samsung devices with different Android versions.

But... There is a problem with LG device. LG-P970 with Android 4.0.4 hangs on Camera.open call. All I seen in logs is:

```
02-14 20:16:48.582: E/CameraProperties(1348): 73: initialize() ENTER
02-14 20:16:48.652: I/LGMDMUICameraAdapter(21106): Camera open, camPid = 21106
02-14 20:16:48.652: I/LGMDMUICameraAdapter(21106): getCameraDisabled = false
```

That's all. And if I run the application in debugger and then suspend it when it hangs, it shows that the application hangs in Camera.native_setup

I really don't have any idea how to fix this issue. I thought that creating Camera instance in Activty.onCreate is not a good idea and moved code to thread with delay, then moved to runable and executed in main thread with delay. It just doesn't work at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can other applications open the camera, like the the original camera app?

Comment: yes, original camera application works.

Comment: I've just found out the solution! I rebooted it and it started working!

Comment: Then everything is fine with the method and it seams, that your application is doing something wrong. Could post the code snippets, where you interact with the camera?

Comment: The code is exactly the same as it's written by google here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#capture-video The first line in Activity.onCreate is Camera.open().

Comment: May be, this might be related??? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829162/failed-to-connect-to-camera-service

Comment: Might be this is related too? https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1578