# how to buliding a camera app on android

Tags: java, android, camera

Hi
i am new to android
my problem is i want to build a camera app for that i just follow the instructions on [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera)(so i am not putting the code here).I take most of the code in the website why because first of all i want to test it then i want to build my app.But it gives error in log cat as below

```
W/System.err(13409): java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
W/System.err(13409): at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
W/System.err(13409): at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:300)
W/System.err(13409): at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:259)
W/System.err(13409): at com.example.testcamera.CameraActivity.getCameraInstance(CameraActivity.java:52)
```

I am testing on HTC and Samsung Mobiles which contains Android-2.3.5 and Android-2.3.6 respectively.

So anybody please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you add uses-permission for camera in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Failed to connect to camera service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829162/failed-to-connect-to-camera-service)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add this to your Android Manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```