# How to write SD card data in Lollipop?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

How to write memory-card data in Lollipop? I want copy image from memory-card but there is an issue about permissions, so help me how I can write memory-card data in Lollipop version?

Comment: Could you share some code?

Comment: Q: What exactly is your code?  Q: What exactly is the error?  Q: What permissions does your manifest have?  Please help us out with a little basic information!

Comment: i want to delete file from sd card .i have added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />   permissions but still not able to write sd card in android 5.0 and higher version of lolipop.

Comment: Did you get any solution ? Can you please share ?

Answer (score 1):

you need to add these permission to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Attention:**

From Android 6 you need to get runtime permission.Android defines some permissions as “dangerous”(like read and write to memory) and some permissions as “normal.” Both are required in your application’s manifest but only dangerous permissions require a runtime request.

Read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33030933/android-6-0-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied/33980679#33980679)!

**Some trick:**
maybe if you change your `targetSdkVersion` in the gradle to `22`, the problem will be solved.

Comment: yes i tried that but still i cant write sd-card data in only android 5.0 and higher version and in other version its works fine