# How to write external storage "permission denied" in instumentation testing on API 23 or higher

Tags: android, android-testing

I cannot write to external storage even in the test case method (inside a subclass of `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`):

```
public void testWriteToStorage() throws Throwable {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test");
    new FileOutputStream(file); // error thrown here
}
```

Error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/test: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:72)
        at com.unacademy.activity.GalleryTestCase.testWriteToStorage(GalleryTestCase.java:49)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
        at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
        at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:192)
        at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
        at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:115)
        at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.AndroidTestResult.runProtected(AndroidTestResult.java:77)
        at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:118)
        at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.AndroidTestResult.run(AndroidTestResult.java:55)
        at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
        at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.NonLeakyTestSuite$NonLeakyTest.run(NonLeakyTestSuite.java:63)
        at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:243)
        at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:238)
        at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.DelegatingTestSuite.run(DelegatingTestSuite.java:103)
        at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.AndroidTestSuite.run(AndroidTestSuite.java:69)
        at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:90)
        at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
        at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
        at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:54)
        at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:240)
        at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1879)
        Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
        at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
        ... 32 more
```

I have the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in the manifest and I know that after API 23 *dangerous* permissions require a consent from user at runtime.

But this is not in the `Application` context; it's in the instrumentation context. Besides, it works on the [AWS device farm sample app](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-device-farm-sample-app-for-android). To the best of my ability I copied the exact same code from there but it still fails here.

**NOTE:** I'm just trying to take a screenshot and store in external storage for AWS Device Farm to pick it up. If anyone managed to do it in some other way please tell me; that'll be really helpful as well.

Comment: are you sure the memory card isnt write protected or locked?? take it out and have a look on the side of the card

Comment: actually if its a microsd im not sure if they have a lock but if thats not the issue try replacing the card

Comment: That isn't the issue. The aws farm sample app works on the same device. Plus its a nexus 5- external storage is irremovable.

Comment: it was just a thought. have a look here for any solution  -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33030933/android-6-0-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied

Answer (score 2):

One thing that comes to my mind is that you're targeting M and maybe not handling the permission request at the runtime.

As you say, in M `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is considered a *dangerous permission* but, the permission handling also changed. Before M, permissions were declared in the manifest and accepted by the user when installing the app. In M, you also have to request the permissions at runtime.

Please check this library that will help you handling the permissions in M.

https://github.com/aitorvs/allowme

I also suggest that you try to avoid external storage whenever possible or even better, storage permissions altogether. Check this fantastic talk from Ian Lake.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C28pvd2plBA

Comment: See my question: `I have the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in the manifest and I know that after API 23 dangerous permissions require a consent from user at runtime.`

Comment: But, are you requesting the permission programmatically? That I can't see from the code you posted. In M it's not enough with declaring the permission in the manifest.

Comment: Dude please read the question description. This is an automated test. Permissions are not supposed to be asked as app itself doesn't need it

Comment: Try to grant the permission using adb:

`adb shell pm grant <PACKAGE_NAME> <PERMISSION_NAME>`

You can automate that inside a gradle task

Comment: On a further note, when you say `Besides, it works on the AWS device farm sample app.`. I checked the github link you posted and AWS target sdk 22, not 23. That's probably why it works for them without needing to do anything extra.

Comment: Oh yes that's true.
And I will automate the command in the gradle task.

Comment: Hi @vedant I am also facing the same issue. Have you got the solution? If yes, please share it.

Comment: @abhishekkumargupta I stopped working on this. Did you try aitor's solution?

Comment: @vedant I make it work by providing Storage Permission via. terminal like 'adb shell pm grant com.example.abhishek.test android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE' before running test case.

Comment: @abhishekkumargupta you should add that as an answer here

Answer (score 0):

I make it work by providing Storage Permission via. terminal(before running test case) like

adb shell pm grant com.example.abhishek.test
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE