# Android Delete Database programmatically: android.system.ErrnoException: chmod failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)

Tags: android

My App stores its database on SD card

DatabaseHandler class

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDb";
private static final String KEY_ROOT_FOLDER=  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/.MYAPP/" + DATABASE_NAME;

 public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator+ FOLDER_NAME+File.separator, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    super(context,  KEY_ROOT_FOLDER, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

So my DB does not delete when user uninstalls the app (because its stores under ExternalStorageDirectory). I want to create fresh copy of the DB when user installing app again.

Therefore im checking first time run on the app and delete previous database by using this code.

```
public void checkReinstallApp(){

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("FIRSTRUN", 0); // Get preferences file (0 = no option flags set)
    boolean firstRun = settings.getBoolean("firstRun", true); // Is it first run? If not specified, use "true"

    if (firstRun) {
        Log.w("activity", "first time");
        isFirstTime=true;
      if(permissionHelper.isPermissionGranted( Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){ //for getting permission Android 6
          SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit(); // Open the editor for our settings
          editor.putBoolean("firstRun", false); // It is no longer the first run
          editor.commit(); // Save all changed settings

          try{
              WebViewActivity.this.deleteDatabase(SET_START_DIRECTORY+"MyDb");

          }catch (Exception e){
             // Error
          }

          File f = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/.MYAPP/");
          deleteFile(f);


      }else{
          permissionHelper.setForceAccepting(true).request(PERMISSION);

      }
    } else {
        Log.w("activity", "second time");

    }

}
```

Im calling checkReinstallApp() method on my

> onCreate

But when i uninstalls the app and reinstall it again it showing no error.But database not getting delete. Please suggest solution for this.

PS-I have tried to delete the folder containing DB file and other files by using this code.

```
  File f = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/.MYAPP/");
              deleteFile(f);


 public  boolean deleteFile(File file) {
    if(permissionHelper.isPermissionGranted(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        if (file != null) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                String[] children = file.list();
                for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                    boolean success = deleteFile(new File(file, children[i]));
                    if (!success) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return file.delete();
        }
    }else {
        permissionHelper.setForceAccepting(true).request(PERMISSION);
        deleteFile( file);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then it's showing this warning message

> : android.system.ErrnoException: chmod failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)

Answer (score 0):

May be you are using android 6.0.So you have to consider runtime permission.

Instant solution: Change targetSdkVersion in the gradle to 22.Not recommended but works.

Refer this link: [Runtime permission EACCES error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33030933/android-6-0-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied)

Comment: yes thats what i have done on the code..please check                                                          WebViewActivity.this.deleteDatabase(SET_START_DIRECTORY+"MyDb");

Comment: Okay so, File dbFile = getDatabasePath(SET_START_DIRECTORY+"MyDb");
boolean is_deleted = dbFile.delete();

Comment: i have checked that too .its returns false.But dbFile.exists() returns true

Comment: Are you sure this block doesn't throw any error? try{
              WebViewActivity.this.deleteDatabase(SET_START_DIRECTORY+"MyDb");

          }catch (Exception e){
Log.e("Error",e.toString)          }

Comment: : android.system.ErrnoException: chmod failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)

Comment: May be any of your code access the database file so it is unable to delete use https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit() and force restart the app.

Comment: Working on android6.0?

Comment: debuging on Android 6.This code works fine on other versions. But not in 6

Comment: im checking run time permission on the code                                                  permissionHelper.isPermissionGranted( Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){ //for getting permission Android 6                                                                                            but still its getting this error. im using permissionHelper class for Android 6 run time permissions

Comment: Change targetSdkVersion in the gradle to 22

Comment: is there any solution other than that. If i change targetSdkVersion to 22.it conflict with other libs on the gradle