# Android: Can't receive images via ACTION_SEND from FaceBook

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

I have a phote-editing app registered on ACTION_SEND for images. This works perfectly.

This is how I access the file from the intent:

```
Uri intentUri = null;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
  ClipData clipData = intent.getClipData();
  if (clipData != null) {
    intentUri = clipData.getItemAt(0).getUri();
  }
}
if (intentUri == null) {
  intentUri = (Uri) intent.getExtras().get(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
}
FileUtil.copyFile(getContentResolver().openInputStream(intentUri), new File(documentPath));
```

Recently, sharing from the facebook app is failing on:

```
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.facebook.katana/cache/fb_temp/.facebook_1475750693248.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:644)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi have you  set the permissions in the android manifest? And have a look at the following links:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854359/exception-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied-on-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854359/exception-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied-on-android) and [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33030933/android-6-0-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33030933/android-6-0-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied)

Comment: AFAIK I don't need any permissions to read from a ContentResolver. This code works well with many other apps issuing ACTION_SEND (galleries, google photos, etc..).

Comment: Since you mentioned this is a recent problem, this could be happening because of the new Android Marshmallow (6.0) permission model. Please take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33030933/android-6-0-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied

Comment: Share from other apps works well for me on Marshmallow, while the share from FB fails both on Marshmallow and pre-Marshmallow.

Anyway, there shouldn't be a permission issue while reading from a ContentResolver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this was solved in the latest update of the Facebook app because it started behaving ok on my app without any changes.