# Getting error permission write_external_storage with runtime permission

Tags: android, permissions

I am using permission runtime in app because android 6+ need it for dangerous permission but until force stop app my code not save file in memory even though user allow this permission in dialog.

**My code for get permission runtime:**

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                    android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != 
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ){
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{
                            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);
            }else{
                saveFile();
            }
```

**Listener for check granted or denied from user:**

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,String[] permission,int[] grantedResult){
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permission, grantedResult);
    switch(requestCode){
        case 1:
            if(grantedResult.length > 0 && grantedResult[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                Log.i("TAG","Permission Granted");
            }else{
                Log.i("TAG","Permission Denied");
            }
    }
}
```

**And error logcat :**

```
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/1B0A-390B/hamed-baradaran.mp3: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

**SaveFile method in this :**

```
public void saveFile(){
    InputStream in;
    OutputStream out;

    try{

        in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.hamedbaradaran);
        out = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/hamed-baradaran.mp3");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
            out.write(buffer,0,length);

        out.flush();
        out.close();
        in.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Please help me

Comment: Are you trying to read any file?  Additionally, have you also added the permission to the Manifest?

Comment: no i want save file

Comment: yes i added permission to manifest

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android 6.0 open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33030933/android-6-0-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied)

Comment: 1B0A-390B - Is this folder already present ?
Also please provide your save method also

Comment: this folder  "1B0A-390B" not created by me

Comment: can you remove the '/' from the file name and try again

Comment: i remove '/' from file name but error has exist

Answer (score 1):

Hello can you try  Permission Request when app start.
I think there error because when u check Permission first time then get error but may be second time image saved my be try it..

Comment: no this method permission runtime in onClick for button and when i click the button until not force stop app next click apply in dialog for permission ,error has exist

Comment: ohk Please Permission Check when app is Start or MainActivity launching but not put code of saveImage there

Comment: okay and when use saveImage ? do you mean from second time equal force stop app ?

Comment: Step1: Chech Permission when start app

Comment: Step 2: When u require saveImage then simple save image method call there no require check permission because we already check permission when start the app ohk try it

Comment: i use your way then i use check permission in onStart method and permission granted in onClick just use saveImage method without check permission but not working

Comment: please you try it and not force stop app after apply request permission and see it work or not?

Comment: full code inserted in up i think the problem not solve and when user apply request have to close compelete app and return again app for save file

Comment: sorry i can't understand where is u error still can u upload your code ?

Comment: dxgroup13571357@gmail.com

Comment: send files please check your mail

Comment: Plz Check your mail i hope that one help you

Answer (score 1):

And try this code  to saveImage

```
public static String SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {
    String filePath;
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images_camera");
    myDir.mkdirs();
    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 10000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    String fname = "Image-" + n + ".png";
    // filePath = "Image-" + n + ".jpg";

    File file = new File(myDir, fname);
    filePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
    //String tmpFilePath = file.getPath().toString();
    IRoidAppHelper.Log("tmpFilePath", filePath);
    if (file.exists()) file.delete();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return filePath;
}
```

Comment: tnx robby but not working for me i use your code and your way but happen nothing else