# How to fix 'EACCES (Permission denied)' error in android?

Tags: android, permissions

I am trying to delete a file on an external SD storage in android by using the following code:

```
filename = "/storage/extSdCard/AAA/testtitle.mp3"
File file = new File(filename)    
file.delete()
```

I am also using the two permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in the `Manifest` (outside the application declaration), and I am using the code suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33030933/android-6-0-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied). The device does not seem to be a Marshmellow device (first answer), and the suggested solution in the third answer also does not help. I still get the same error:

```
remove failed: EACCES (Permission denied) : /storage/extSdCard/AAA/testtitle.mp3
```

What else can I try?

Comment: You do not have arbitrary read/write access to [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/15/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) on Android 4.4+. I do not know how you got that `File`, but your problems begin there. Use the Storage Access Framework to get a `Uri` pointing to the content on removable storage, then use `delete()` on `DocumentFile` to try to delete the content.

Comment: I tried: `DocumentFile cfile = DocumentFile.fromFile(file);
                cfile.delete();` but got the same error again...

Comment: Use the Storage Access Framework to get a `Uri` pointing to the content on removable storage. Use `DocumentFile.fromSingleUri()` to get a `DocumentFile` pointing to that piece of content represented by the `Uri` from the Storage Access Framework. Then, use `delete()` on the `DocumentFile`.

Comment: I get a new error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.ContentProviderClient.call(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.os.Bundle)' on a null object reference`

Comment: Code used: `Uri myuri = Uri.parse(filename);
                DocumentFile cfile = DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(getApplicationContext(), myuri);`

Comment: `Use the Storage Access Framework to get a Uri pointing to the content on removable storage. Use DocumentFile.fromSingleUri() to get a DocumentFile pointing to that piece of content represented by the Uri from the Storage Access Framework. Then, use delete() on the DocumentFile. `

Comment: `Use the Storage Access Framework to get a Uri pointing to the content on removable storage.`. It seems as if you fail to start in this way.

Comment: I am using:  `Uri myuri = Uri.parse(filename);`. Is that incorrect?

Comment: You did not get that filename from the Storage Access Framework, in part because content does not have a filename. As I wrote originally,  I do not know how you got that `File`, but your problems begin there.

Comment: I am not quite following. Why can't you provide some example code, starting from the filename of the file which is "/storage/extSdCard/AAA/testtitle.mp3"? I am not an expert in android!

Comment: "Why can't you provide some example code, starting from the filename of the file which is "/storage/extSdCard/AAA/testtitle.mp3"?" -- because that filename is useless. Please read [the blog post that I linked to in my first comment](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/15/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

Comment: I want to remove a file with the given filename. I tried to do the following: `File file = new File(filename);
                boolean deleted = file.delete();`. What is the problem with this code?

Comment: I do not understand the blog. There is no code in that blog. Just description of some things I do not quite understand, and comparison of version etc...

Comment: Question updated with actual code...

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about the "Storage Access Framework" or why the `file.delete()` does not work. So I have found a solution that seems to be way easier: 1. Instead of deleting a file, I add the filename to a text file. 2. After a while I connect the phone to Linux and open this text file with a python script. 3. The python script then removes the files. Because in python you can just delete a file damn easy.... Thanks anyway...