# Android: Failed to open file (Permission denied) despite Permission Granted for reading and writing

Tags: java, android, android-studio

There are multiple such questions out there, however, they are not able to solve the problem.

### build.gradle

- compileSdkVersion - 29
- buildToolsVersion - 29.0.3
- midSdkVersion - 26
- targetSdkVersion - 29
- Android Studio - 3.6
- Testing Device OS - Android Q (10)

### Android Manifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

### Activity.java

```
String filepath = '/path/to/file';
filepath.exists() // true
filepath.canRead() // false
filepath.canWrite() // false

ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED // true
ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED // true
```

The `MainActivity` is not able to read the file despite the fact that the file exists and the relevant permissions have been granted. Is there any other solution to this problem?

Comment: What version of Android are you testing on?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33030933/android-6-0-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied?rq=1

Comment: updated the question with android version details.

Comment: You have no access to arbitrary locations on external and removable storage on Android 10+. The `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` workaround will not work on Android 11+. So, either change where this file is located, use the Storage Access Framework, or use `MediaStore`.

Comment: @Tom thanks for pointing it out. But that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @CommonsWare that answers it. Thanks.