# Android Camera: Failed to connect to service

Tags: android, android-camera

I am trying to develop a face tracking app using the Google Vision API ([API doc](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/package-summary))

This is my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="true"/>
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES" android:value="face"></meta-data>

    *activities*
```

This is my code:

```
private void startCameraSource() {
    try {
        mCameraSource.start(mPreviewHolder);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //Error handling
        Toast.makeText(this, "Could not start camera!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

This is the error in Logcat:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:520)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:361)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource.zzEu(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource.start(Unknown Source)
```

Why does this happen (...on an Xperia Z3 compact 5.1)?

**UPDATE:**

I spotted a new error. I think it might be the reason why my code is not working.
 How can I resolve this problem?

```
W/ServiceManager: Permission failure: android.permission.CAMERA from uid=10241 pid=26845
E/CameraService: Permission Denial: can't use the camera pid=26845, uid=10241
```

Comment: where's the SurfaceView and it's SurfaceHolder and associated functions? e.g. onSurfaceCreated()

Comment: I created the surface view in my layout file and I use `getHolder()` to get the SurfaceHolder object. I did not overright any methods, but that shouldn't be a problem, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem in the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829162/failed-to-connect-to-camera-service) question.
I had to move

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="true"/>
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES" android:value="face"></meta-data>
```

int the `<manifest>`-tag.